# Dynamic text fields in iPhone are possible or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to place textFields on iPhone screen dynamically but I am not getting an idea how to start it.

I have to place a textField where ever the user taps. when a user tap on screen a text field or textView should be places there and user can write a comment over there.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want your textfield to appear exactly where the user tapped?

Comment: Yes @frank exactly. at least x axis and y axis

Comment: Ok. And where is your problem exactly : get the coordinates of the touch or add a UITextField programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible to add `UITextField`'s to a screen dynamically.

A `UITextField` is just another view (albeit one that inherits from `UIControl` and then `UIView`).  After you create a `UITextView` programatically, you can add it via `addSubview` to the view that is on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the coordinates of where the touch happened. You could then dynamically create a textfield and set its origin in that coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

yes possible ..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

is called on the view controller when user touches the view..

there you can allocate a textField and set its center to touch center.