# adding uitextfields dynamically at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I want to generate textfields dynamically in my app  scenario is
I am having a textfield and a button if entered the number 2 in textfield and pressed the button, then 2 texfields must be generated on view controller

Comment: use for loop to create textfields

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic text fields in iPhone are possible or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480371/dynamic-text-fields-in-iphone-are-possible-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using this code;

```
int num=yournum;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
    textField.tag = i;
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

And to access the correct text field afterwards you'd call 
`[self.view viewWithTag:tag]`.

Comment: i have implemented the same code but still it doesnt work for me.

Comment: -(void)dynamicTextfeilds  
{  
    NSString *string = Points.text;  
    int Pointsvalue = [string intValue];      
    NSLog(@"%d",Pointsvalue);      
    for (int x=0; x < Pointsvalue ; x++)  
    {  
          txtFldFrame = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 278, 45)];
          txtFldFrame.tag = x;  
        [self.view addSubview:txtFldFrame];  
        [self.view viewWithTag:x];  
    }  
}

Comment: First thing you are using instant of textfield so it will not work create whole textfield in method. and second thing you are satting same frame to every textfield so every textfied will overlap on another. and third thing `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` is for accesing textfield outsite this method so dont write it in the method.

Comment: generated textfeilds but only one textfeild is displayed. added this code for another textfeild but not working correctly.                                    txtFldFrame = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,txtFldFrame.frame.origin.x+30, 278, 45)];
txtFldFrame.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

Comment: Still you are using instant of `txtFldFrame`. i have told you to use new textfield like this `UITextField *textField` instead of instant.

Comment: I am done with this issue, i have generated the text boxes. thanks for help.

Comment: ohh ok than fine your welcome.

Comment: i have generated 2 textfeilds i have assigned tag x tofirst one and tag y to second one but while accessing with " [self.view viewWithTag:tag]"  result is only the value from first textfeild. why?